# Не вижу причину ошибки: "You have an error in your SQL syntax..."

Tags: php, mysql

Выходит ошибка: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"

```
<?php
require "connectsql.php";
$id_transaction = array_shift($_POST);
$query = "UPDATE transactions SET status='fact' WHERE transactions.id = " . $id_transaction ;
$res_query = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
header('Location: /link2.php');
?>
```

Код работал. Потом перестал. Ничего не менял О_о

Comment: уверен, что id сюда не прилетает

Comment: @АлексейШиманский точно - NULL !!

Comment: var_dump($id_transaction); ?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос строковое значение SQL запроса вместо кода как пример.